# h:selectOneMenu send me previus value

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="filtroUnidad" immediate="true" style="width:120px" value="#{class.idUni}" label="#{bundleComunes.unidad}">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundleComunes.seleccionar}..." itemValue=""/>
  <f:selectItems value="#{class.lUnidadesValidas}" var="lUni" itemValue="#{lUni.id}" itemLabel="#{lUni.descripcion}"/>
  <f:ajax render="sisArm" event="change" listener="#{class.changeOneUnidad}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

I have this selectOneMenu but when I call to listener idUni ever have previous value. Somebody know how to change that??

Method java

```
/**
* changeOneMenuP.
*/
public void changeOneUnidad() {
  if(idUni == null) {
    lSistemasValidas = sisDao.findByValido();
  } else {
    lSistemasValidas = escDao.findByUnidadUbicacion(idUni, true);           
  }
}
```

idUni is a String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove immediate="true" from `<h:selectOneMenu>`:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="filtroUnidad" style="width:120px" 
                 value="#{class.idUni}" label="#{bundleComunes.unidad}">
```